# Read file from res folder in J2ME

Tags: file, java-me, inputstreamreader

I've tried this code but always get me 'is' as NULL. My file is located at "res" folder.

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    if(is == null) {
        System.out.println("'is' is null");
    } else {

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);

        String line = null;
        // Read a single line from the file. null represents the EOF.
        while ((line = readLine(reader)) != null) {
            // Append the read line to the main form with a linefeed ('\n')
            str.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    }
```

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thx!

Comment: What is the value of the filename?

Comment: Can you tell me the `filename` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+filename);
```

Comment: Ok! I'll try it I'll feed back with results

Comment: Hi!I've tried that code:

`StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
     InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+filename);
     if(is == null) {...`

but always returns null